# I have a Fortran program that should give segmentation fault but it doesn't

Tags: fortran, segmentation-fault

As simple as the title. I have a student who got a segmentation fault and I was trying to prove him why does this happen. Instead, I ended up wondering why it doesn't.

The code is this:

```
program main                                                                                 
  implicit none                                                                              
  real*8, allocatable:: u(:)                                                                 
  integer :: i                                                                               
  allocate(u(2))                                                                             


  do i=0, 1000                                                                               
     u(i) = i                                                                                
     print *, u(i)                                                                           

  enddo                                                                                      

end program main
```

I would expect this to crash at `i=3`, but it doesn't. Compiled with both ifort and gfortran with -O0 to -O3

Comment: _Why_ should it give a segmentation fault?  You haven't written a valid Fortran program so you can't really expect any particular behaviour to happen.  That is, it may crash (with segmentation fault) or it may not, depending on any number of factors not determined by the program itself.  Your program could just print "Hello" and still be produced by a conforming Fortran compiler.

Comment: To quote a part of a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30637372/3157076) "If you write code that accesses element 141 of an array with 140 elements Fortran, like many other compiled languages, will happily access the next location in memory after element 140. In general you haven't a clue what data the program is interfering with. If you are lucky the next location in memory is outside the address space the operating system has allocated to the program and the operating system stops the program immediately and reports a segmentation fault."

Comment: Most likely your OS gives the program a large chunk of heap storage even though you only allocate `u(2)`.  In general, your program will segfault when your program reaches outside this space.  This happens when `i=15095` on my machine but is not something you should rely on.  If you compile with `-fsanitize=address`, your program will crash on the first iteration when `i=0`

Comment: Once you go beyond and arrays bounds, there is no guarantee of what will happen, except of course that your data will be meaningless.  On your student's computer, memory was arranged so that he hit memory outside the programs allocation.  On your computer, this did not happen.  Again, there's no guarantee what will happen outside of an array's bounds.  It just, "Heere there bee dragons!"

Answer (score 1):

What about turning on the bounds checking option for compilation and then explaining to the student that a seg fault is a common result for out of bounds access when the extra overhead for bounds checking is not in place?