# Toy example of a segfault in Fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

What is an example of code that deliberately causes a segfault in Fortran?  I tried the following in msys, but all I got was a warning and the naughty access of the baddata array just printed 0.

I need this for learning purposes but also as a test case for writing code to handle gracefully when things like this happen when calling an external Fortran function

```
program segfault

  implicit none

  real, dimension(10) :: baddata
  integer i

  do i=1,10
     baddata(i) = 1.0
  end do

  print *, baddata(1)
  print *, baddata(1024)

end program segfault
```

compiled with: `gfortran segfault.f90 -o sefault` yields:

```
(base) C:\Coding\Fortran>gfortran segfault.f90 -o segfault
segfault.f90:13:19:

   13 |   print *, baddata(1024)
      |                   1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (1024 > 10) in dimension 1

(base) C:\Coding\Fortran>segfault
   1.00000000
   0.00000000
```

Comment: Seems like an odd request to learn how to write crappy code, but here you go.  `real, allocatable :: a(:) ; print *, a(1) ; end`

Comment: perfect, thanks @evets.  Yes, usually SO is where you ask how do I fix my code, not how do I break it, but all work and no play...

Comment: as an aside, free 25 rep points if you want to copy it into an answer...

Comment: @evets, see this question for the reason I needed this toy example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831483/how-to-handle-occaisional-segmentation-fault-in-f2py-module

Comment: This is strange, did gfortran make array bound checking the default when no optimizations selected? That certainly would be a great thing. But in that case even the example by evets could be caught.

Comment: @VladimirF, I thought gfortran has done this (detecting array bounds violations when it can at compile time, then issuing a warning) for some while?

Comment: @francescalus I see, this one is compile-time. Yes, that was done possibly from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you cannot do this "within Fortran".

Segmentation faults come from attempting to access parts of memory without permission.  The Fortran language is specified in such a way that if you try to access a lump of memory without permission (such as accessing an array element not within bounds) then you don't have a valid Fortran program.  That's part of the "not within Fortran".  Another part is that if you have a (valid Fortran) program which correctly references things, then the processor is required to ensure that the program is treated in a correct way (which doesn't involve segmentation faults).

Any "toy example" with a segmentation fault is going to depend on specific behaviour of a particular compiler, operating system, and so on.  These could vary depending on versions, compile- and run-time options.

For example, in this question we see how a simple attempt to access out-of-bounds access is detected by the compiler and even when running doesn't result in a segmentation fault.  Other cases are in other questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58186674/3157076).  More detail on when an array access results in a segmentation fault can be found in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30637372/3157076).

Why is this detection important?  Well, if the compiler detects that you are attempting out-of-bounds access, then it could just as correctly, under the Fortran language, treat your

```
  print *, baddata(1024)
```

as though you'd written

```
  print *, -1231.516, "<- I hope you like this value I made up for you"
```

Perhaps your best bet would be to try the classic null dereference:

```
  integer, pointer :: i=>null()
  i=0
end
```

But this isn't a Fortran program.  You may need to do a lot more work to get a reliable segmentation fault.  This could move you well beyond a "toy" example.

Alternatively, if you can generate a SIGSEGV (again, this wouldn't be a Fortran thing), perhaps with a procedure not defined by Fortran, then you may find that easier.