# how to handle occaisional segmentation fault in f2py module

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, fortran, f2py

I have an f2py module that I am using.  The core of the code I did not write myself, just the f2py wrapper to use it.  Because of time constraints, and the knowledge that his code is short term need only, meaning I want to throw it away, not fix it, what I want to do is just catch the behavior when a segfault occurs and try again.  The below code is an example:

`sums.f90`

```
subroutine bad(a, b, c)

  real, intent(in) :: a, b
  real, intent(out) :: c
  real, allocatable :: d(:)
  real :: r

  call random_number(r)

  if (r < 0.5) then
    print *, d(1)  ! segfault here
  end if

  c = a + b

end subroutine bad
```

compile with: `f2py -c sums.f90 -m sums`

and now if I just call it repeatedly, then sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
3.0
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
3.0
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
Segmentation fault: 11
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
3.0
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
3.0
>>> python -c "import sums; print(sums.bad(1,2))"
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Now I know the right thing to do is fix the segfault..., but I am hoping there is a way I can just handle it and move on from within the calling Python code.  Is this possible?

--CURRENT APPROACH--
My current solution is to run my program inside a subprocess using `subprocess.run` and if the return code indicates a segfault, try again a certain number of times before giving up.  Going to leave the question unanswered though as its not really what I asked originally, and also, probably not a recommended practice, but just what is helping me cope with my current situation.

Comment: Do you wish to fix it within by modifying the generated python code or by modifying the original fortran code

Comment: The Fortran is broken - you are accessing d( 1 ) before d is allocated. As such you will have to change the fortran.

Comment: OK, maybe I understand what you want now, you want to catch a segfault in the python. Please understand that what you have done on the Fortran side is invoke undefined behaviour. As such anything can happen, including right results, wrong results, World War III and if you are very lucky a segmentation fault and a core file. The only reasonable way to fix such a case is fix the segfault - otherwise the results of the program are just totally unreliable.

Comment: @IanBush, I get all of that.  What is happening is that I calling a particular subroutine literally 3 trillion times, and once in awhile it  crashes on me.  I could spend the time to fix it... and I will if I have to, but I was just hoping there was a way for me not to have to spend that time debugging since the subroutine will never be used again after I'm done with it here

Comment: I'm afraid the only proper solution is to debug the routine